# The value of 'form' must inherit from 'BaseModelForm' in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I am making a simple form to receive user's information and display on next page using django.
but I am getting the error The value of 'form' must inherit from 'BaseModelForm',and when i try to inherit from ModelForm it displays the error that there is no module ModelForm.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import NameForm
from django.forms import ModelForm

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = NameForm
        fields = '__all__'
        your_name = forms.CharField(label="Your name", max_length=100)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Album
from .forms import NameForm
from django.forms import *
from django.db.models import *
from models import *

admin.site.register(Album)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NameForm  

admin.site.register(NameForm, MyModelAdmin)

class NameFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NameForm
```

name.html

```
<form action="/profile/see" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ NameForm }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Naming your model `NameForm` and your form `NameForm` as well is going to cause problems. In your `forms.py`, use the import `from django import forms`, then subclass `forms.ModelForm`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `NameForm` defined in all the files you posted and you also have a model called `NameForm` that you're importing in the `forms.py` file. You shouldn't name a form the same name as a Model.

You're also importing every thing using `from foo import *` syntax which is really bad because you could be overwriting your `NameForm` with your model definition or vice versa.

In your HTML your doing `{{NameForm}}` which is incorrect. The proper way to render a form in HTML using the `forms.Form` class is `{{ form }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **"forms.Form"**, you need to use **"forms.ModelForm"** with **"admin.ModelAdmin"** as shown below:

```py
# "forms.py"
               # Here instead of "forms.Form"
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # ...
```

```py
# "admin.py"
                   # Here
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
                    # Here
class NameFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
```